# TypeScript 3.x: Access properties of type unknown

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript3.0

I read from the TypeScript documentation, that you can't access properties from the type unknown:

```
// No property accesses, element accesses, or function calls

function f11(x: unknown) {
    x.foo;  // Error
    x[5];  // Error
    x();  // Error
    new x();  // Error
}
```

But I don't understand why? If I can assign every value including an object, why can't I access the properties?

I'm batteling the following scenario: I have an object of type `any` and I pass it to the `Object.entries` method and then call `forEach`.

Because it's of type `any`, the forEach call argument will be an array with the first element being of type string and the second one of type unknown.

In my case, that second element is an object, but I can't access its properties without converting its type, which seems wrong to do.

Here is an example, which throws a TS error (just an abstraction, I know it doesn't make sense to declare it as any in this case):

```
const obj: any = {
  val1: "someval",
  val2: {
    some: "some",
    object: "object",
  },
};
Object.entries(obj).forEach(el => {
  if (el[1].some) {
    console.log(el);
  }
});
```

[image: error preview]

This could also just be wrong typings for the `Object.entries` method I guess, but I'd still like to have explained, why I can't access properties of type unknown.

So as a summary my questions are:

1. Why can't I access properties of type unknown even though type unknown can be an object?
2. I guess there is a reason for the above question, but shouldn't the `Object.entries` return an array w/ element nr. 0 of type string and element nr. 1 of type any?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think that in order to address your question, it is important to give some context on `any` vs `unknown`. While you can find an exhaustive comparison list in the [official TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type), I think I can take some liberty and shorten the article to a few statements: `any` is basically a one-type-fits-all and therefore **is not type-safe**. By type-safe I mean you can access a runtime property of `any` that doesn't exist.

`unknown` is different. `unknown` is the opposite of `any` in this regard. It represents a type-safe version of `any` by stating "I won't pretend I fit everything because I don't". So `unknown` requires additional casting to the desired type in order to work (because it doesn't possess any properties on its own).

Now, to the actual question. Why `Object.entries` use `unknown` instead of `any`? Because it is safer to say "cast this unknown value to whatever you need before usage, *I won't assume* that I know anything about this type" than "I don't know what kind of type it is, but *I'll assume* that it has all possible properties of all possible types".

Comment: Oh, so the `unknown` type is actually meant to be "reassigned" to a type with accessible properties? So the developer is reminded, when doing something like accessing a property, that he has to be sure it exists, so he won't make a mistake that could cause a runtime error. While with the `any` type, he could just do that, which is potentially wrong, therefore not type-safe.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue
but I try this technique to solve it

```
// choice is a custom data type 
export interface Choice {
  id: string; 
  isSelected: boolean; 
  score: number;
  status: string; 
}
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.tableForm.value)) {
      if (value) {
        let choiceItem  = value as Choice;
        let choiceIds = [String(choiceItem.id)];
         
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The definition of `Object.entries(...)` (taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts#L38)) is:

```js
entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
```

Since you explicitly defined `obj` as `any`, the call to `Object.entries` returns

```js
[string, unknown][]
```

You can simply remove `: any` when declaring `obj` and TypeScript will infer its type from the definition.

In that case, the call to `Object.entries` would return:

```js
[string, string | { some: string; object string; }][]
```

To answer your questions:

> Why can't I access properties of type unknown?

The compiler tries to avoid runtime errors by checking at compile time. If you really know what you're doing, you can always cast an `unknown` to an `any`. For example:

```js
const value:any = el[1];
```

> I guess there is a reason for the above question, but shouldn't the Object.entries return an array w/ element nr. 0 of type string and element nr. 1 of type any?

It actually returns `[string, unknown][]`.

Comment: I do understand that in my example it doesn't make any sense to declare it as any. It's just an abstraction. i.E when the object comes from a fetch, it would be type any...

Comment: I added a summary to my question. (I do know plenty workaround for my problem I just don't know why it exists)

Comment: I appreciate your updated answers, but they both just say that it "is the case" and "it happens" but I actually asked **why** is that the case and **why** is type unknown returned even though from my point of view, `any` would be more precise