# react-router's `useRouteError` has return type unknown, how to access its property

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I started with react-router 6.4.3 on a new TS project, and found that its useRouteError hook has return type `unknown`. I am not very sure how to correctly access the properties of the returned error object.

[image: error accessing property of unknown type]

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59841548/2224448), I believe I have to cast it to an interface I am expecting, but I want to make sure asking the community here, if this is the right way or is there any better way:

[image]

Comment: Until someone tells us if there's an official typing definition and where to find it, I will use your solution :-)